# Converting byte[] to DateTime returns a wrong year

Tags: c#, datetime, arrays, win-universal-app

My application is a UWP app written in C#.
I need to open a stream from a file, read 8 bytes into a byte[], then convert the byte array to DateTime.
I'm using the following code:

```
static public async Task<DateTime> GetDateTime(StorageFile FileName)
    {
        Stream inStream = await FileName.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
        byte[] dt = new byte[8];
        await inStream.ReadAsync(dt, 0, 8);
        long longDT = BitConverter.ToInt64(dt, 0);
        DateTime resDT = DateTime.FromBinary(longDT);
        return resDT;
    }
```

the bytes to read are:

```
C0 3B 12 D1 68 8A D1 01
```

which should convert to "30/03/2016 09:44:55".

If I run my app, the code above returns "30/03/**0416** 09:44:55", with a difference of 1600 years.
What's wrong with my code?

Comment: How did you serialize the file?

Answer (score 3):

The 1600 years can be fixed by using `DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc`.

`FromBinary` - The value of this property (Ticks) represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 (0:00:00 UTC on January 1, 0001, in the Gregorian calendar),

`FromFileTimeUtc` - A Windows file time is a 64-bit value that represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.) Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

As you can see, 1600 years difference.

Comment: I get this: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException non è stata gestita dal codice utente
  HResult=-2146233086
  Message=Not a valid Win32 FileTime.
Parameter name: fileTime
  ParamName=fileTime
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(Int64 fileTime)
       at CZIPGenius.czip4.<cz4GetDateTime>d__10.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---